# ASP.NET MVC5 - razor and vue.js in same page, show razor's html block after ajax back

Tags: razor, vue.js, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a page both exist vue.js block and razor.

cshtml:

```
@{
   var myData2 = ViewBag.MyData2 as MyDataModel;
}
<div id="vueApp">
   <div v-if="myData != null">
       .....
   </div>
</div>

@if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(myData2.Id)
{
   <p>@myData2.Description</p>
   <div>...</div>
}
....(Other razor syntax)....
```

javascript:

```
new Vue({
   el: "#vueApp",
   data: {
      myData: {}
   },
   methods: {
      getInfo: function() {
         axios.post("API URL", {requestData: "123"})
            .then(function(response) {
               myData = response.data;
            })
            .catch(function() {
            })
      }
   }
})
```

How do I render the razor block and vue block together after the vue.js ajax back?

Answer (score 0):

the razor code is interpreted **before** the page is sent to the client, you should do **both** checks with vue

```
<div v-if='myData2.Id!==null'>
    <P> @ myData2.Description </ p>
    <Div> ... </ div>
</ Div>
```